# NoMethodError in Users#new "undefined method `simple_form_for' for #<#<Class:0x9f9b568>:0xaa02440>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

My new.html.erb code in views/users:

```
 <h1>Sign Up</h1>

 <%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :username %>
 <%= f.input :password %>
 <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
 <%= f.button :submit %>
 <% end %>
```

this is the error:

```
 undefined method `simple_form_for' for #<#<Class:0x9f9b568>:0xaa02440>
```

I know what this error is asking for:

```
 def simple_form_for
 end
```

but the problem is where to put it.
Also this is my users_controller.rb:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
     def new
          @user = User.new
     end

     def create
         @user = User.new(params[:user])
         if @user.save
             redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.'
         else
             render action: "new"
         end
     end

     def show
         @user = User.find(params[:id])
     end
 end
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to use this gem?: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.  If so, including it properly in your gemfile as described should allow this to work.  You would not have to define this method on your own.

Answer (score 3):

That's not what it's expecting at all.

`simple_form_for` means your app is expecting to have the Simple Form (https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem available, which provides that method for your forms to use. You should either install the gem, by adding it to your Gemfile, or rewrite your form to use Rails form helpers instead of Simple Form.

Comment: i do have the gem installed, but with bootstrap installed

Comment: is it part of your app, ie. included in your `Gemfile` ?

Comment: hmm. can you try removing the `=` from `<%= simple_form_for` in your view?

Comment: still the same... makes no difference

Answer (score 1):

If it does not find the method but you had installed the gem. In that case, I think you forgot to restart the server. Restart the server and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Gemfile: gem 'bootstrap-sass'
         gem 'simple_form'

you must have a setting for bootstrap 
"rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap"

Answer (score 0):

you of proplem is rails no method `simple_form_for` you can try with `form_for`
and read more http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically saying that the `simple_form_for` method is not available (as you know).

The **solution** is to determine *what* that method is, and how it needs to be used.

---

[**Simple Form**](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)

The error is caused by *simple form* not being available in your app.

To include it, you just have to add the gem:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'simple_form'
```

--

If you don't have the `simple_form` gem installed, you'll be able to fix the issue by using Rails' [`form_for`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object) which isn't that much different:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field     :username %>
   <%= f.password_field :password %>
   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried your way using form_for instead of simple_form_for and it shows this: `undefined method 'users_path' for #<#<Class:0xa025490>:0xaeeded0>`

Comment: Which routes do you have?