# NoMethodError in Messages#new undefined method `simple_form_for' for #<#<Class:0x0000000d639ba8>:0x0000000ed05cd8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

Help I dont know what Im doing wrong. I already installed the gems, put them in my gem file, did the bundle install, and restarted the server by using rails s. Why am I getting this error?

_form.html.erb:

```
<% simple_form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title, label: "Message Title" %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

messages_controller.rb:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController


  def index
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
  end

  private

    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:title, :description)
    end

end
```

gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304238/nomethoderror-in-usersnew-undefined-method-simple-form-for-for-class0x9

Comment: Is not as that didnt work

Comment: have you tried to restart your server?

Comment: I did but it still didnt work. I installed the gem correctly and added to my gem file, did the bundle install, then restarted my server. Still cant figure it out